# Como mudar a cor de apenas um elemento num form-group com vários outros?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

Olá!

O que acontece comigo é o seguinte:

Estou usando o Bootstrap Validator para validar os campos do meu formulário. Porém, ao rodar a página, os campos estão ficando da seguinte forma. Perceba que o campo "Código" está desativado. Foi validado apenas o "Razão Social". Gostaria que apenas este campo aparecesse em vermelho.

[image: campos]

O problema é que tenho que manter ambos os campos no mesmo form-group para que fiquem na mesma linha. Separando os campos em form-groups diferentes, a cor muda corretamente, mas os campos ficam desalinhados. Abaixo meu HTML.

[image: html]

Há alguma forma de aplicar a cor somente para os campos que eu desejar?

Answer (score 1):

Para manter a estilização separada, você não pode usar mais de um campo de formulário dentro do elemento com a classe *form-group*.

Veja em: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline. Mesmo com cada campo em um "form-group", eles ficam na mesma linha, nesse caso você pose usar uma classe adicional para os campos que devem ficar em linhas separadas.

Answer (score 0):

Você não irá aplicar a cor somente para os campos que desejas – pelo contrário, você irá *excluir* as cores dos campos que não desejas.

Para isso, você adicionará à propriedade `excluded` do `bootstrapValidator` os campos que estiverem `:disabled`:

```
$(formSelector).bootstrapValidator({
    excluded: ':disabled'

    [...]
});
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme! 

Legal, obrigado pela resposta! Mas neste mesmo formulário tenho outros campos que ficam posicionados na mesma linha que não estão desativados, e o mesmo problema ocorre. Neste caso, eu desejaria que a cor fosse aplicada de acordo com cada campo que eu validasse, mas quando eu valido apenas um da mesma linha, os outros aplicam já a cor antes mesmo de eu clicar. Há alguma propriedade que possa resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que deva criar um código CSS separado para este campo ou retirar `CssClass="form-control"` do `txtCodigo`.

Comment: Oi Rogers! Obrigado pela resposta!

Se eu retirar o CssClass="form-control", o campo perderá os atributos aplicados pelo css do Bootstrap. E tenho outros campos abaixo onde ocorrem o mesmo problema, sendo que estes não estão desativados. Sabe me dizer se há outra alternativa? Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Inverta o seu código para ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label></label>
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma, você terá as `colunas` separadas do `form-group` e poderá validar separadamente os `inputs`.